# Wifi BSSID Signal Strength and Channel allocations IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, wifi, bssid

Id like to know if it is currently possible to conduct network scans in Ionic on android and IOS, effectively what id like to know is if its possible to read the 5.2ghz and 2.4ghz networks and return BSSID its signal strength and what channel its using coded under the ionic framework. currently building a network planning tool and its something that I would like to include. I had heard that at one point IOS was not allowing these tools onto the App Store, but ive also heard now that they do allow it.